# writing a sql that return 3 rows to one row as a list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT points
FROM   memberevents AS me
WHERE  memberid = memberevents.memberid
ORDER  BY id DESC LIMIT 3;
```

It returns the following:

```
**points** 
    123
    234
    146
```

But I want to create SQL that would return as follows (just one record that concat the points with "-"):

```
**points**

123-234-146
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `group_concat()` function, but in a particular way:

```
SELECT substring_index(group_concat(points order by id desc separator '-'), '-', 3)
FROM   memberevents AS me
WHERE  memberid = memberevents.memberid;
```

The `order by` clause mimics your original `order by`.  The `separator` uses the separator you want.  The `substring_index()` chooses the first three elements, analogous to the `limit 3`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation to let me understand.

Answer (score 2):

Try [**`GROUP_CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT (P.points SEPARATOR '-')
FROM (
  SELECT points
  FROM   memberevents AS me
  WHERE  memberid = memberevents.memberid
  ORDER  BY id DESC LIMIT 3) P
GROUP BY P.points;
```